# Why does the Randomized-Select algorithm return the element at Array[low] when (low === high)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Can somebody explain to me why the algorithm is returning the element at `array[low]` when the `if` case on line 4** is true. Couldn't the `order` not exist if `partition` recurses down to a length of 1 on the GREATER side of the subarray from `pivot+1 to high`?

```
function randomizedSelect(array, low, high, order) {
  var pivot, count;

  if (low === high) {   **
    return array[low];  **
  }

  pivot = partition(array, low, high); 
  count = pivot - low + 1;
  if (count === order) {
    return array[pivot];
  } else if (order < count) {
    return randomizedSelect(array, low, pivot-1, order);
  } else {
    return randomizedSelect(array, pivot+1, high, order - count);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that the randomized select algorithm does is to select a number from array lying between the indices `low` to `high`. If there are more than 1 numbers exist between indices `low` and `high` then it will skip the `if condition` and go for partition. But, here the  line 4 is the edge case, where only one number exist in between low and high i.e., `low` and `high` are basically same. So, we can return anything, even if you `return array[high]`, the result will be same as its the same index(number). Hope this might have helped you.

Comment: You point out a clear and undeniable fact, indeed I had seen that case already. The problem I had with the algorithm is that it would return the `array.length - 1` element when an `order` of greater than array.length - 1 was inputted. But now I see that obviously the original author assumes that the person operating the algorithm knows the length of the array they are inputting and thus, `order` would be in bounds. It seems that a quick case of checking whether `order > array.length` would eradicate this potential misleading output in the odd case.